# Predicting Centre of cylinder using external measurements

Tags: geometry

[cylindar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWGPW.jpg)

I am trying to determine the centre of a ring shaped cylinder based on external measurements

I have a measurement device that looks at this cylinder and when the system operates  will measure in mm's, 2 points on this cylinder, let's assume the distance from the measurement device to the inner and outer dainters of the ring are

Point a=115.5mm
Point b=24.9mm

I need to predict based on these external measurements what the center point of the shaft would be, and also what the external daiamter would be

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

We have to make some assumptions…….

Use the device (D) to probe multiple times to detect the nearest point (N) on the object. Then, DN = x, the shortest distance.

[image]

Use the device (D) to probe multiple times to detect the far most point (T) on the object before a miss (i. e. an infinite or error reading). Then, DT = t, the tangent length.

By power of a point, $t^2 = x(x + 2r)$. From which r, the external radius can be found.

Comment: I have have not explained my questions well enough, see attached image, i do not have a solid circular diameter but more like spokes, that dont come out from the centre shaft, so what i have is intermitent high points and low points which i see as i rotate my shaft

Comment: I should add also that the inner shaft may not be concentric

Comment: @Lee Maybe the spokes can be taken off temporarily when taking the measurements. If there is no rules governing the two centers, it is impossible to find.

Comment: the spokes are in a helix around the centre shaft that is unknown in daimteter and these are welded I do have a known daiamter I can reference first if that helps, however the shaft the spokes if you like are welded to may not be fully parralel/concentric to this part

Comment: In thoery at lest the inner shaft and the outer daimeter of the spokes should be parralel and concentric however there is a chance the inner shaft may be bent due to the way it is welded

Comment: @Lee Maybe a more detailed diagram can help in understanding the actual structure of the object.